# Executing a Postgresql query in Python that creates a table

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm creating a Flask webapp that displays the results of various Postgresql queries. As part of the initialization, I want to run a query that creates a table in Postgresql containing all of the data that I will need for subsequent queries. My problem is that, although the webapp appears to initialize correctly (in that it doesn't throw up any exceptions), I have no idea where the new table is being stored (I believe I have namespaced it correctly) and I can't access it from any other queries.

Code below:

```
import psycopg2 as p2
import pandas

conn = p2.connect("dbname='x' user='y' host='z' password='password' port='1234'")
cur = conn.cursor()

def exec_postgres_file(cursor, postgres_file):
    statement = open(postgres_file).read()
    try:
        cursor.execute(statement)
    except (p2.OperationalError, p2.ProgrammingError) as e:
        print "\n[WARN] Error during execute statement \n\tArgs: '%s'" % (str(e.args))

exec_postgres_file(cur,'/Filepath/initialization_query.sql')
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM schema.new_table""")
rows = cur.fetchall()
new_table_df = pandas.DataFrame(rows)
print new_table_df

exec_postgres_file(cur,'/Filepath/query1.sql')
rows2 = cur.fetchall()
query1_df = pandas.DataFrame(rows2)
print query1_df
```

Where new_table is the table created during initialization_query. query1 is trying to access new_table but an exception is thrown up after the second exec_postgres_file statement:

> relation "new_table" does not exist LINE 10

Assume initialization_query is:

```
select *
into schema.new_table
from schema.old_table
where id in    ('A','B','C','D','E','F')
;
```

and query1 is:

```
select date, sum(revenue) as revenue  
from schema.new_table
group by date
;
```

These both work when I run the query in a database management tool like Navicat.

Comment: Please post both your create code, and your access code.

Comment: why are you capturing exceptions in your exec_postgres_file? better to leave them "bubble up" and make the whole thing fail fast with a proper traceback, instead of trying to keep going (and have it fail later anyways..)

Comment: BTW, it would be useful for understanding what's going on to see the contents of your ``initialization_query.sql`` file.. I guess there is something wrong with your queries.

Comment: Worked it out - I didn't commit the initial transaction to the back end.

Answer (score 0):

This is what Flask-Migrate has been made for: http://flask-migrate.readthedocs.org/en/latest/